# Is "mobbing" used in BrE and AmE to refer to harassment in the workplace.

Tags: word-usage

The concept of ***[mobbing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobbing#In_the_workplace)***, originally used referring to animals, according to the extract below, is now applied also to human beings, and is used specifically to refer to subtle aggressive behaviours  in the workplace:

> - ***Konrad Lorenz, in his book entitled On Aggression (1966), first described mobbing among birds and animals,*** attributing it to instincts rooted in the Darwinian struggle to survive.
> - In the 1970s, the Swedish physician Peter-Paul Heinemann  applied Lorenz's conceptualization to the collective aggression of children against a targeted child.
> - ***In the 1980s, professor and practising psychologist Heinz Leymann applied the term to ganging up in the workplace.*** Leymann noted that one of the possible side-effects of mobbing is post-traumatic stress disorder and is frequently misdiagnosed. After making this discovery he successfully treated thousands of victims at his clinic in Sweden.

Mobbing in the workplace:

> - British anti-bully researchers Andrea Adams and Tim Field have used the expression "workplace bullying" instead of what Leymann called "mobbing" in a workplace context. ***They identify mobbing as a particular type of bullying that is not as apparent as most, defining it as "an emotional assault".*** (Wikipedia)

I could not find evidence in any dictionary on the meaning and usage of "mobbing" with the connotation cited above.

The following piece may  help understand why, but it refers to the year 2000, [psychologicalharassment.com](http://www.psychologicalharassment.com/mobbing-academe.htm):

> - ***Strangely, recognition of Leymann’s discovery has been slower in coming to the English-speaking world.***  Newsweek published a popular summary of research on workplace mobbing in 2000, but only in its European edition. ***In Britain and America, attention has focussed less on mobbing than on the different but related problem of bullying,*** and, occasionally, on one of its extremely rare possible results: the outbursts of extreme violence, that from time to time make headlines across the country.

Question:

Is "mobbing"  used in BrE and AmE to refer to subtle aggressive behaviour aimed at discrediting and causing psychological pressure in the workplace or is it still not used as suggested above ?

Comment: It's a new use to me. The current term would just be bullying or even microagression in the context of workplace. Note that general dictionaries often do not include technical definitions created academically.

Comment: @Mitch - mobbing appears to be used with a different connotation with respect to bullying: https://books.google.it/books?id=JlJoyD84BfAC&q=%22mobbing%22&dq=%22mobbing%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBiYzZi8vKAhWFVhQKHZ1uBukQ6AEIOTAD

Comment: I'm familiar with *fans mobbing celebrities* - [Crowd round (someone) or into (a place) in an unruly way](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mob), and I've occasionally encountered OP's usage as it relates to social animals/birds. But never in the context of "collective bullying" by *people*.

Comment: [**Workplace harassment** is also known by many other names. **“mobbing”**, “workplace bullying”, “workplace mistreatment”, “workplace aggression”, and “workplace abuse” are all either synonymous or belong to the category of workplace harassment.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workplace_harassment)

Comment: In the US I would generally read "mobbing" to mean literally having a mob present.  As in "the store was mobbed" (meaning it was full and activity was frenetic).

Comment: The term is actually used in English and American specialised literature, but is appears it is not commonly recognized from what I can read from the few comments. http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2013/12/28/bullying-at-work-workplace-mobbing-is-on-the-rise/ - http://bullyonline.org/old/workbully/mobbing.htm

Comment: Mobbing USA - http://www.mobbing-usa.com/resources/faq/n - How to Combat Workplace Mobbing - http://www.manageangerdaily.com/2010/03/how-to-combat-workplace-mobbing/ - Mobbing in the workplace - http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/mobbing-in-the-workplace.html

Comment: You're going to have to answer your own question, and see if that spurs others to agree or disagree. And confirm if the term mobbing (= workplace harrassment) is used/known in the UK and in the US. Why don't you mention it's used in Italian? [Mobbing: che cos’è il terrore psicologico sul posto di lavoro](http://www.proteo.rdbcub.it/article.php3?id_article=85)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - as you probably know it is a known and used in Italy and I am surprised that, though it is found in many  British and American articles, it is totally unkown to native speakers. There is no English dictionary that cites it.  Mobbing: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mobbing/

Comment: I repeat my question, why don't you say it's used in Italian? What did Italians say in the past that covered bullying in the workplace? Mobbing is a relatively new loanword in the Italian language, but I can't think what it used to be called in Italian. EDIT mobbing exists among work colleagues, it's not just confined to employer and employee.

Comment: This is curious, on Google images the term [*mobber*](https://www.google.it/search?q=mobber&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSxq63iszKAhXEog4KHSnYCygQsAQIPQ#imgdii=n7nEApj9WvqYvM%3A%3Bn7nEApj9WvqYvM%3A%3BPXkOSjWOsBa3qM%3A&imgrc=n7nEApj9WvqYvM%3A) throws up images of school and work bullying. The loanwords "mobber" and "mobbing" seem to be used in Germany. The English for "mobber" is *mobster*, which is another word for gangster.

Comment: The umbrella term is  "harassment", which covers the whole spectrum, sexual, physical, psychological..etc. I'm pretty sure that is the answer, but seeing as I don't live in the US nor in the UK, so I can't say whether "mobbing" is completely unheard of or known in Anglophone countries.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - that is the question, but from the comments above I think the answer is.."no" it is not commonly used and understood.

Comment: Wait... what exactly is the question here? 'Mobbing' surely is used and understood in AmE for any kind of collective bullying by humans. Is it restricted to such behavior _only_ in the workplace? No, not at all. Is that your question or is just the general meaning your question?

Comment: @Mitch - sorry if the question is not clear, I am referring to mobbing used as in the following cases related to a form of harassment in the workplace.                   Mobbing - USA  - http://www.mobbing-usa.com//?s=mobbing Mobbing in the workplace: http://www.manageangerdaily.com/2010/03/how-to-combat-workplace-mobbing/

Comment: @josh61 mobbing can be applied to such behavior in the workplace sure but is not restricted to there.

Comment: @Mitch - if a colleague of yours were a victim of mobbing, what would you think they were a victim of? In Europe that would refer only to a form of subtle, psycological harassment in the workplace.

Comment: @Josh61 in BrE or using 'mobbing' as a borrowing in Ger/Fre/Ita/etc? In AmE, not knowing anything else 'mobbing' would evoke the image that they were walking along the street and a whole lot of people attacked my colleague. If at work I would think 'oh that's a weird metaphor for bullying, why weren't they clearer and say 'workplace mobbing'?'

Comment: @Mitch - OK, I understand, but what about the link I showed you before, mobbing is actually a term officially used with that connotation by US Authorities. "*In the United States, Dr. Noa Zanolli Davenport and two colleagues, have published “Mobbing, Emotional Abuse in the American Workplace,” copyright 1999, Civil Publishing Society, Ames, Iowa. Dr. Davenport has become an expert witness in the identification of “mobbing.*” http://www.mobbing-usa.com/mobbing-an-article-by-susan-rae-sampson/

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-anglicism#Multiple_languages) classifies it as *pseudo-anglicism*:

> *Mobbing* (German, Norwegian, Polish, Serbo-Croatian, Swedish) – bullying

According to [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/44521) at Workplace.SE, the term is recognized within German law, and *Mobbingberatungsstellen* appear to exist across Germany (for example).

That explains why, even if recognized as a term by some psychologists, *mobbing* need not be understood in its meaning stipulated by psychologists by  native speakers of English.

Comment: I probably should've asked at Worrkplace.SE, I didn't think about it. The question should probably be migrated.

Comment: @Josh61 If it is a language issue, it belongs here rather than there, I think. However, the word looks like legalese, following its origin in psychology, so the usage will probably follow from its incorporation in the regulations peraining to workplace. With that, Workplace.SE might help (especially as many users seem to be from the US).

Comment: What surprises me is the fact that it is common in Europe and in Italy too. Unluckily mobbing issues are more and more common and TVs and papers often talk about that. I can't believe that the same issues are not common in the  UK or the USA, where they are probably referred to differently. But mobbing is different from bullying.

Comment: @Josh61 Anyway, if you migrate, please let me know, I'd rather delete this. (Or perhaps the mods will do that for me.)

Comment: @Josh61 I am no expert, but I think the issues themselves existed for centuries (as anyone knows who made their way through the schooling process. It is difficult not to notice the pattern). It's just that they are recently perceived as a problem, and classified in detail.

Comment: The 'pseudo-anglicism' reference is very interesting. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Josh61 It's a language question. "Mobbing" is called something else in the UK, and of course the phenomenon exists in the US and the UK. I'm pretty sure "harassment" covers  work-related "discrimination" behaviour. Sexual harassment perhaps being the most well-known and publicized.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Sexual harassment can happen everywhere, if it happens in a workplace it is mobbing.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the US, **Hostile work environment** seems to be the equivalent of the phenomenon that is commonly called "mobbing" in Italy, and in different parts of Europe,  which the OP refers to in his question.

> In United States labor law, [**a hostile work environment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostile_work_environment) exists when one's behavior within a workplace creates an environment that is difficult for another person to work in. Common complaints in sexual harassment lawsuits include fondling, suggestive remarks, sexually-suggestive photos displayed in the workplace, use of sexual language or off-color jokes. Small issues, annoyances, and isolated incidents typically are not considered to be illegal. To be unlawful, the conduct must create a work environment that would be intimidating, hostile, or offensive to a reasonable person. An employer can be held liable for failing to prevent these workplace conditions, unless it can prove that it attempted to prevent the harassment and that the employee failed to take advantage of existing harassment counter-measures or tools provided by the employer.
>
> Source: Wikipedia

2. In the UK, the government uses the following term

> **Workplace bullying and harassment**
>
> [Bullying and harassment](https://www.gov.uk/workplace-bullying-and-harassment) is behaviour that makes someone feel intimidated or offended. Harassment is unlawful under the Equality Act 2010.
>   Examples of bullying or harassing behaviour include:
>
> - spreading malicious rumours
> - unfair treatment
> - picking on someone
> - regularly undermining a competent worker
>     denying someone’s training or promotion opportunities
>
> Bullying and harassment can happen:
>
> - face-to-face
> - by letter
> - by email
> - by phone
>
> The law
>   **Bullying itself isn’t against the law, but harassment is.** This is when the unwanted behaviour is related to one of the following:
>
> •age •sex •disability •gender (including gender reassignment) •marriage and civil partnership •pregnancy and maternity •race•religion or belief •sexual orientation

Comment: Interesting, so the answer to my question is "no".

Comment: For more detail: https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/discrimination-at-work/common-situations/discrimination-at-work-bullying-and-harassment/